# CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIME)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, where-clause

i am trying to work with timestamps and manipulate the data out of them so i can measure different things in our database.

currently i have a column that holds a "DATE" but in fact contains a whole stamp 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

i want to be able to grab all entries where "DTIME" between "09:00" and "09:15" however have not been able to cast it correctly.

If i  was to output the column without any conversion it would look like this

```
  SELECT ia.DTIME3
  FROM ISIS_AUDIT ia
  WHERE ia.DTIME3 like to_date('24/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

OUTPUT: 24/JAN/19

if i was to convert it to_char,

```
  SELECT to_char(ia.DTIME3, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM ISIS_AUDIT ia
  WHERE ia.DTIME3 like to_date('24/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

OUTPUT: 24/01/2019 07:10:52

I want to be able to take this DTIME3 and find entries between the times but CAST and CONVERT to TIME doesnt work.

This is my working option but it outputs the date still and i dont want to have to specify the date so it can be run across any day of the week.

```
  WHERE ia.DTIME3 between to_date('24/01/2019 09:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('24/01/2019 09:15:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

OUTPUT: 24/01/2019 09:00:01

Comment: `between` is inclusive; do you really want to include exactly 09:15:00, or actually only up to 09:14:59.999...? The latter looks more likely - and that's what GMB's second approach with `extract` will do, because of the `<`.

Answer (score 3):

> currently i have a column that holds a "DATE" but in fact contains a whole stamp 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

That's what [Oracle `DATE` datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413) does : storing a date *and time* (without fractional seconds, that belong to the `TIMESTAMP` datatypes). There is no specific format in Oracle for date only (without time).

To filter on the time of the day, you can use [the `TO_CHAR()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) to convert your date to a string that represents its time, and that you can compare :

```
TO_CHAR(ia.DTIME3, 'hh24:mi') BETWEEN '09:00' AND '09:14'
```

You can also [`CAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm) the date to a timestamp and use [the `EXTRACT()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639) :

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(ia.DTIME3 AS TIMESTAMP)) = 9 
AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(ia.DTIME3 AS TIMESTAMP)) < 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types; both have year, month, day, hour, minute, second components (`TIMESTAMP` also has fractional seconds). Oracle does not have a `TIME` data type.

Instead, use `TRUNC()` to truncate the time component to midnight and add an interval literal:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ISIS_AUDIT
WHERE  DTIME BETWEEN TRUNC( DTIME ) + INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE
             AND     TRUNC( DTIME ) + INTERVAL '09:15' HOUR TO MINUTE;
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i will try this method and see what happens.

Comment: i did work out a way to access the time of the data however if i wanted to check if a "START TIME" and "FINISH TIME" fell between "09:00" and "09:15" how could i do that.

Comment: @DavidZammit Just replace `DTIME` with `START_TIME` and then add a duplicate `BETWEEN` clause for `END_TIME`.

Answer (score 0):

```
and ia.DTIME1 not between to_date('&&S_DATE 08:50:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('&&S_DATE 09:20:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')               
                and ia.DTIME1 not between to_date('&&S_DATE 11:50:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('&&S_DATE 12:40:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                and ia.DTIME3 not between to_date('&&S_DATE 08:50:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('&&S_DATE 09:20:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')               
                and ia.DTIME3 not between to_date('&&S_DATE 11:50:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('&&S_DATE 12:40:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

i was trying to do this way however i noticed if i have a start time of 08:30 and a finish time of 09:30 then it falls between 09:00 and 09:15 so i want to exclude it from the table. the current WHERE clause im using is quite specific and will only exclude if the timestamp contains the values specified.

Really it would want to read "DTIME1 to DTIME3 not between 09:00 and 09:15"

Comment: Just revert the `WHERE` clause I provided you with : `WHERE NOT( EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ia.DTIME3) = 9 AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ia.DTIME3) < 15 )`. PS : this answer from you should have been posted as an edit to your question, or a comment on other answers.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i will take a look and see how it runs.